# Logout when the application is force closed

Tags: android, authentication, logic, logout, autologin

I want to implement the function : if user dosen't checked the autoLogin CheckBox, clear the login user information and logout when the application is quit normally or force closed(clean the memeory).

I write the code `clearAutoStart()` to clear user information both in `finish()` and `OnDestory()`.
When the user press back button twice,  the  `finish()` will execute, and will logout success. But as you know, if the application force closed, `OnDestory()` will not execute all the time. So in this situation, it will not logout success.

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitBy2Click();        //quit normal
    }
    return false;
}


private static Boolean isExit = false;

private void exitBy2Click() {
    Timer tExit = null;
    if (isExit == false) {
        isExit = true; 
        Toast.makeText(this, "press again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tExit = new Timer();
        tExit.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isExit = false;  
            }
        }, 2000); 
    } else {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    clearAutoStart();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    clearAutoStart();       
    super.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i("ws", "---->>SmarterActivity onStop");
    super.onStop();
}

public void clearAutoStart() {
    RememberUser rememberUser = RememberUser.getInstance();
    if (rememberUser.getIsAutoStart() == false) {
        Log.i("ws", "---->>clearAutoStart getIsAutoStart false ");
        UserLocalStore userLocalStore = UserLocalStore.getInstance();
        userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
        userLocalStore.clearUserData();
        Log.i("ws", "---->>clearAutoStart getIsAutoStart false OK ");
    } else {
        Log.i("ws", "---->>clearAutoStart getIsAutoStart true ");
    }
}
```

I try to add the `clearAutoStart()` in `onStop()`, but this means if I press the HOME button , the application will logout.

Answer (score 0):

When you press HOME onPause() is called and then onStop().

So you can put a member variable that keep the track of what is happening:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    mIsPause = true;

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i("ws", "---->>SmarterActivity onStop");

    if(!mIsPause)
        clearAutoStart();

    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to clear data in onStop(), I want to clear the data when the application is force close.

Comment: remember that is not execute always: if(!mIsPause)
        clearAutoStart();